# Crashing due to "No package identifier when getting value of resource number..."

Tags: java, android, xml, debugging, resources

Okay after searching through the various threads that I could find on this topic, and trying everything that seemed to work for the others... I have succumb to the need to post my own issue.

As a total noob to Android and Java, you will have to forgive the need to talk to me like a child :)

I have an app that has 3 activities so far. A main window that works as a navigation screen to choose one of the other two. The first works perfectly, but when I try button number 2... it crashes.

I have some code that I am trying to run onCreate... so when I saw that it was often the XML layout that caused the crash.. I commented out the Java code... and presto the layout loads fine.

putting the code back in, it crashes once again.

Looking in LogCat I see a line that says "No Package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x0000000d"

Then all sorts of lines about fatal exceptions and shutting down the VM.

So, garnering confidence from other posts, I went to the R.java file to see what resource has that ID... and it's not in there. They ALL start with 0x7f...  now the ONLY one that ends in "d" is a textview with the ID "game_Answer1". But I am not certain if that is what it's referring to or not.

I did try the Eclipse clean command, as well as deleting the R.java... same issue.

Below is the java code that seems to be crashing... again, hold the laughter at my spaghetti code as this is attempt #2 in Java beyond a hello world app!

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
public class playgame extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gamelayout);

    //set up first question
    genQuestion();

}


Random generator = new Random();

public void genQuestion() {
    int i = generator.nextInt(25);
    int correct = generator.nextInt(2)+1;
    TextView g_answera = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_Answer1);
    TextView g_answerb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_Answer2);
    TextView g_answerc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_Answer3);


    g_answera.setText("-");
    g_answerb.setText("-");
    g_answerc.setText("-");

    if(correct==1){
        g_answera.setText("!");
    }
    if(correct==2){
        g_answerb.setText("!");
    }
    if(correct==3){
        g_answerc.setText("!");
    }

}
```

Below is the XML layout associated with this issue... just in case I am missing something obvious:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff"  android:id="@+id/gamelayoutwrapper">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/games_animalnameFrame" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/game_animalname" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textSize="60sp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:gravity="right" android:text="__nteater"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/game_animalimageFrame" android:layout_below="@+id/games_animalnameFrame" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/game_animalImage" android:src="@drawable/elephant" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingBottom="10dp"></ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gameLettersFrame" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="#cccccc">

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/game_Answer1" android:text="A" android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:paddingRight="20dp" android:layout_gravity="left" android:clickable="true" android:textSize="100sp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:textColor="#090999" android:background="#ccccFF"></TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/game_Answer2" android:text="B" android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:paddingRight="20dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:clickable="true" android:textSize="100sp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:textColor="#090999" android:background="#ffcccc"></TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/game_Answer3" android:text="C" android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:paddingRight="20dp" android:layout_gravity="right" android:clickable="true" android:textSize="100sp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:textColor="#090999" android:background="#ccffcc"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 50):

I ran into this same issue a while ago, I assume that it is fixed but I figured an alternative answer is always welcome :) When using the setText() method you CANNOT send through primitive data types such as int and double, rather convert to string and then send through the string. This fixed my issue when it popped up

Comment: This, amazingly, fixed my issue. Well worth a 50% increase of your rep!

Comment: It should be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't allow uppercase resource names

Rename

> R.id.game_Answer1

to

> game_answer_one

etc for the other's you have

Comment: That's interesting. But its weird, i have resources with uppercase letters e.g. firstName, and that works fine. i'm guessing it has something to do with the underscore separator perhaps?

Comment: Yes they are resource id's created within XML files, but resource **files** cannot have uppercase text.

Comment: You can check to see if you are getting this error, in your standard output console you would see something like '[2011-02-11 23:12:09 - APP NAME] Error in an XML file: aborting build.'

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to look at the ID name for a LinearLayout to make sure I was accessing the correct one in my code. This error for me happened because I had forgotten to add an android:id="@+id/myid" into one of my XML layout files (because that file wasn't the focus of my attention at that point!)

Answer (score 0):

in your R.java file, does an id for gamelayout exist? This should be located in 
`public static final class layout {
    }` in the R file? Thats the first important step in determining why your application crashes.

Comment: yes, it does exist in my R.java file. And, like I said, if I don't reference any TextViews the thing loads fine. In fact, I commented out the TextView references, and used the random integers to load a random image, and THAT works... there is something wrong with my TextViews but I am at a loss!

Answer (score 0):

Android (unfortunately) doesn't accept resource identifiers with upper-case letters. 
Also, make sure you are defining your namespace in the root view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/game_answer1" 
            android:text="A" 
            android:paddingLeft="20dp" 
            android:paddingRight="20dp" 
            android:layout_gravity="left" 
            android:clickable="true" 
            android:textSize="100sp" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:textColor="#090999" 
            android:background="#ccccFF"
            />             
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

there might be others errors in your project because of which your R.java is not created well. hence while executing it is not getting the resource with that id. R.id contains id of all the resources in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite late to answer, though might be useful for those to will find this thread through search.

The setText method requires the identifier as an argument.
So, there should be a string in the values/strings.xml with name like "empty_answer", containing the value "-". In other words, the line like:
    -

Then the setText should be called like:
    g_answera.setText(R.string.empty_answer);

Possibly, what happens in your case is that the string "-" was somehow turned into resource id 0x0000000d, which of course doesn't exist in your app. Although it's strange that such code was compiled.

One more comment: in Android it IS POSSIBLE to name resources like IDs with Capital characters. What is NOT possible - to have Capital chars in the NAME of resource files.